# alternative for ui grid in angular js

Tags: sql, angularjs, node.js

alternative for ui grid in angular js  best in  export and import data in to the grid

Comment: What have you built so far? At which point do you fail to succeed? This question is way too broad (let alone the fact you're not even asking a question)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your question should include a clear outline of your *specific* issue, a summary of what you have already tried and the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we have enough information to be able to help!

Answer (score 0):

Smarttable was OK, but the documentation is not great (tbh, neither is ui-grid's though). This link also gives more: https://www.angularjs4u.com/demos/top-10-angularjs-table-demos/